# Add a webpart Button

Tags: 2010, web-part

I want to add a button with webpart, then to place a script and launch it with the button. But I can't find the possibility to add a button with webpart. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Content editor web part (under Media & content) and add your button there. You can click on 'edit source' in the ribbon to add HTML.

[image]